# Email Tracking Data Modeling

Tags: postgresql, nosql, data-modeling

I am working on a system that will be sending a bunch of emails every month. One of the core features of this system is that it needs to be able to track the various state changes that will happen with an email (processed, delivered, opened, converted). Each of these events is pretty much a status, timestamp, and perhaps a small bit of unstructured metadata.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to data model this. It seems that a standard relational database might not be the best fit for a few reasons:

- There's not much relation required - very few queries will depend on other tables/documents
- There's a huge amount of data (easily 1M records per month)
- The records quickly becomes unimportant (after a few months, specific documents are rarely queried, although aggregate metrics matter)

As far as a data model, there's three things that exist in this system:

- The "email job" - a top-level grouping of many emails that were sent out in a batch
- The email record
- The status updates for those email records

I need to perform the following sorts of queries:

- What is the current status of Email X?
- What is the status history of Email X (when did each of the status events happen)?
- How many emails in Email Job Y are in each status?

Any thoughts on the best way to model this? A relational database sounds expensive and non-performant for this use case... is this one of the rare places with a NoSQL/Mongo/DynamoDB solution makes sense?

Comment: Just a note. 1M rows per month is not "huge" for modern hardware. If you keep detailed history for 10 years it is only 120M rows. I have a table with 100M rows that contains detailed data for the last 7 days. In addition to this detailed data I have separate tables that hold daily and weekly summaries. We use SQL Server, but I believe any modern RDBMS can handle tables of this size, just use proper indexing.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment under your question : a RDBMS can provide you a performant solution.

With this few information I will attempt to provide you a possible solution but I will take the freedom to make some assertions:

- You do not need the mail content in your database but just an external reference to it
- A mail is searchable by its id, its external id or the combination of [the expeditor, the receiver, the date of emission]
- The system does not take care of any user management

[image]

This schema should do the trick.

With that you need some indexation :

- BTREE index in all cases
- Mail (external_id)
- Mail (expeditor, receiver, emission_date desc)
- Mail_has_Mail_Status (date desc)

If you want to be cautious :

- Partitionning is possible on mail and mail_has_mail_status. Even sub-partitionning in mail_has_mail_status table (it will be easier to maintain if you want to just archive or drop old data) (pg_partman)
- Do things on different tablespaces (hot data, cold data, indexes)

The rest is a question of simultaneous access on your cluster and how much money you have for the material. But :

- SSD are cheap those days and will save you in many cases.
- If you want to RAID : physical card and avoid the RAID 5 family.
- If you need high availability : https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/3553182172805148419?source=blog
- High frequency processor (the number of cores is not that much important. 4 is enough in many cases)
- High frequency memory. And not that much if you do not have the mail core in this database.

With this quantity of data you can easily benchmark your architecure.

Of course to really do the architecture job that you required, you will need a little more precisions in your analysis and a little more time to conform your architecture to your real needs. And after that benchmarking it of course.